# How to fix 'Can't assign requested address'. Even I tried many different port on mac with python

Tags: python-3.x, networking

I want to make a connection between a server and a client. Actually I don't have any knowledge about networking. So I tried to make below codes but when I run the codes always give same problem  'Can't assign requested address'.I need help to solve this problem and also some suggestion to begin networking with python 3

Even I tried many different port it gives same error 49

```
import socket


def Main():
    host = "78.188.213.49"
    port = 5000

    s = socket.socket()
    s.bind((host, port))
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print("Connection from: " + str(addr))

    while True:
        data = c.recv(1024).decode(('utf-8'))
        if not data:
            break
        print("From connected user: " + data)
        data = data.upper()
        print("Sending message: " + data)
        c.send(data.encode('utf-8'))

    s.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Comment: /Users/macbook/PycharmProjects/Network/venv/bin/python /Users/macbook/PycharmProjects/Network/tcpserver.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/macbook/PycharmProjects/Network/tcpserver.py", line 27, in <module>
    Main()
  File "/Users/macbook/PycharmProjects/Network/tcpserver.py", line 9, in Main
    s.bind((host, port))
OSError: [Errno 49] Can't assign requested address

Answer (score 12):

I usually get this error when Mac doesn't find a route to the address temporarily, and this command might help:

```
sudo route delete [destination address]
```

Comment: Similar error trying to connect via ssh this fixed it! thanks :) Error was "ssh: connect to host <ip-address> port 22: Can't assign requested address"

Answer (score 1):

I see following issue with your approach :

- First try running your code as root. The port You are trying may be reserved port.
- Try changing the port to some other random number mostly > 10000.
- Make sure `78.188.213.49` belongs to your any one network interface. Or try changing the address to `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/macbook/PycharmProjects/Network/tcpserver.py", line 26, in <module>
    Main()
  File "/Users/macbook/PycharmProjects/Network/tcpserver.py", line 10, in Main
    c, addr = s.accept()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 212, in accept
    fd, addr = self._accept()
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Comment: I have tried to change the address to 127.0.0.1 but different error came up

Comment: Thank you it is running now

Comment: Can you follow up and post how you got this working?